# What is isnad of this Hadith about Muhammad made dua for rain?

Tags: hadith, isnad

O Ka'b, relate to us something from the Messenger of Allah." Ka'b said: "When a man came and said to the Prophet of Allah, 'Seek rain for the tribe of Muzhar,' I heard the Prophet say: 'You are a bold man. You want me to seek rain for the tribe of Muzhar?' The man said: 'O Messenger of Allah, you have sought victory from Allah and He gave you victory. You supplicated Allah and He answered you.' The Messenger of Allah raised his hands and said: 'O Allah, give us a saving rain, good and productive, general and heavy, now and not later, beneficial and not harmful.' Allah responded to his supplication. It was not long before the people came complaining about the profusion of rain, and damage to their dwellings. The Messenger of Allah raised his hands and said: 'O Allah, around us and not upon us.' The clouds began dispersing left and right. Apparently it is found in ahmad and ibn hajar but i cannot find the isnad in English. Thank you

Comment: I doubt if the isnad of any work of hadith has been translated. This hadith is also found in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/39) from a different narrator.

Comment: [Here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/14567#p1) is the chain in Arabic of the version in [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/14569#p1) from Ka'b حدثنا أبو معاوية، حدثنا الأعمش، عن عمرو بن مرة، عن سالم بن أبي الجعد، عن شرحبيل بن السمط قال: قال لكعب بن مرة

Comment: @UmH [qala Rassulullah](http://qaalarasulallah.com/) actually transliterates the sanad.